# Color won't change on Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I'm a beginner coder trying to build a website for a beach I go to but when I try and change the color of the text on the Navbar, it doesn't show up.

I've already tried changing the identifiers and also using different formats.

This is one of the parts I'm trying to change in my HTML:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active" class= "colorMe"><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="members-login.html" class="colorMe">Members</a></li>
          <li><a href= "lifeguard-login.html" class= "colorMe">Lifeguards</a></li>
      </ul>
```

(By the way members-login is a password page)
This is the CSS for the corrospondin HTML:

```css
.colorMe{
    color:darkgreen;
}
```

So when I try and pull up a preview pf the website using the Brackets software, the color doesn't change... Please help!

Comment: Where in your HTML does an element have the class `colorMe`?

Comment: @j08691 is on the ball here. Your CSS is correct, and your HTML is correct too, however the CSS isn't affecting the HTML because you're not using your `colorMe` class in your HTML.

Comment: I changed my HTML to include class= "colorMe" but when I do that, it still doesn't color the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could something like this

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a class= "colorMe" href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="members-login.html" class="colorMe">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href= "lifeguard-login.html" class= "colorMe">Lifeguards</a></li>
  </ul>

 .colorMe {
    color: darkgreen;
  }
```

note: if this isn't the right solution you might have to provide more code example
for us to see where is `.colorMe` called in your HTML

Comment: I changed my question to reflect my changes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: check my edited code, on you first `<li>` tag you have two classes.  put `class="colorMe"` into `<a>` tag

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked. I used that as well as adding an !important tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no element you're showing us, that has the class "colorMe" assigned to it.

If there is, you want to make sure that it's placed on the actual `<a>` tag. If that doesn't work, then the issue is that there's a stronger inheritance from bootstrap's side. You can override that by using !important, or doing something like,

```
ul > li > a.colorMe
```

Comment: you can see the question: I changed it to the code I have now and it still doesn't work. Do I need to add !important?

Comment: Read the answer, as you have not done what I suggested. The issue is with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a class="colorMe" href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="members-login.html" class="colorMe">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href= "lifeguard-login.html" class= "colorMe">Lifeguards</a></li>
  </ul>

.colorMe {
    color: darkgreen!important;
 }
```

I have seen that you have used two class attribute which is bad. It should only be one. And remember when dealing with bootstrap components you should add !important to your css value to override the bootstrap value.
And you should link your css file after the bootstrap css file. So that your css file would be the last to cascade.